# set JavaScript variable value on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button on my page which executes a JavaScript function on click. Now I have a variable in my function whose value should be the one which user enters in input text box. Here is my code.

```
    <input type="text"> </input>
    <button id ="buttton" class="button" onclick="myfunction()">Create Envelope</button>

    <script>
    function myfunction() {
    var sub =""; // I am thinking of writing jquery 
}
   </script>
```

Now by the time user clicks the button my variable sub should hold the value which user enters in the input field.

Answer (score 3):

> Use `.value` property of `InputElement`(JavaScript) or `$(ELEMENT).val()` method of `jQuery`

To select the element, give unique `ID` to element. There are other ways to select the element as well which are `class-selector` or `attribute-selector` and many more!

```js
function myfunction() {
  var sub = $('#input').val();
  console.log(sub);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='input'>
<button id="buttton" class="button" onclick="myfunction()">Create Envelope</button>
```